# Groupby and counts in ranges and spread in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have `dx`:

```
   City     Val1        Val2
x1  N1      0.0000      1.0
x2  N1      790.9980    6.0
x3  N2      110.3755    4.0
x4  N1      191.8150    2.0
x5  N2      574.3100    3.0
x6  N1      725.4000    4.0
x7  N3      362.7000    2.0
x8  N1      196.4800    1.0
x9  N3      230.8200    2.0
x10 N1      259.8830    1.0
```

Reproducible example:

```
dx = pd.DataFrame({'City': {'x1': 'N1',
  'x2': 'N1',
  'x3': 'N2',
  'x4': 'N1',
  'x5': 'N2',
  'x6': 'N1',
  'x7': 'N3',
  'x8': 'N1',
  'x9': 'N3',
  'x10': 'N1'},
 'Val1': {'x1': 0.0,
  'x2': 790.998,
  'x3': 110.3755,
  'x4': 191.81500000000003,
  'x5': 574.31,
  'x6': 725.4,
  'x7': 362.7,
  'x8': 196.48,
  'x9': 230.82,
  'x10': 259.883},
 'Val2': {'x1': 1.0,
  'x2': 6.0,
  'x3': 4.0,
  'x4': 2.0,
  'x5': 3.0,
  'x6': 4.0,
  'x7': 2.0,
  'x8': 1.0,
  'x9': 2.0,
  'x10': 1.0}})

dx
```

I want to group them by `City` and count the number of `Val1` in ranges `[0,200,400,600,800,1000]`.

Expected output:

```
      (0, 200]   (200, 400]   (400, 600]   (600, 800]   (800, 1000]
City
N1     2          1            0            2            0
N2     1          0            1            0            0
N3     0          2            0            0            0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) and add missing categories by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with [`cat.categories`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cat.categories.html):

```
bins = [0,200,400,600,800,1000]

s = pd.cut(dx['Val1'], bins=bins)
df = pd.crosstab(dx['State'], s).reindex(s.cat.categories, axis=1, fill_value=0)
print (df)
Val1   (0, 200]  (200, 400]  (400, 600]  (600, 800]  (800, 1000]
State                                                           
N1            2           1           0           2            0
N2            1           0           1           0            0
N3            0           2           0           0            0
```

If use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) or [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) are added all categories:

```
df = dx.pivot_table(index='State', columns=pd.cut(dx['Val1'], bins=bins), aggfunc='size')
```

---

```
df = dx.groupby(['State', pd.cut(dx['Val1'], bins=bins)]).size().unstack()
print (df)
Val1   (0, 200]  (200, 400]  (400, 600]  (600, 800]  (800, 1000]
State                                                           
N1            2           1           0           2            0
N2            1           0           1           0            0
N3            0           2           0           0            0
```

Answer (score 1):

OR you can try:

```
df = df.assign(bins=pd.cut(df.Val1, bins=[0, 200, 400, 600, 800, 1000])).pivot_table(
    index='City', columns='bins', values='Val2', aggfunc='count')
```

`OUTPUT`:

```
bins  (0, 200]  (200, 400]  (400, 600]  (600, 800]  (800, 1000]
City                                                           
N1           2           1           0           2            0
N2           1           0           1           0            0
N3           0           2           0           0            0
```